# Weird redirection in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I don’t know what I did (I haven’t changed anything as far as I’m aware) but all pages in my local magento 2.1 installatin, including admin url seem to redirect to catalog/product/view/id/1/
I think it started when I tried to change from production mode to developer mode and I got an error that some directory in var/view_preprocessed wasn't empty

Admin URL is http://localhost/magento2/admin_txezgg/ and redirects to http://localhost/magento2/admin_txezgg/catalog/product/view/id/1/key/cb1b86e778c363acb15ecf571a2557d6cf06413595c15eb65800f3dd350dba23/

I have done upgrade, cleared/disable/flush caches, reindex, restart laptop and the last thing I did was to uninstall and install magento again, and still is happening!!

Has anybody ever come across this? This is driving me insane...